# Filling out a form ms-word VBA / Most effective intelligent navigation through Word

Tags: vba, ms-word

**Summary:** My company sends out letters to customers and wants me to write a macro to fill in different text form fields that have been set up in a word document since a very limited amount of things change between different letters sent out. I've done macros in excel, but this is my first encounter with ms-word macros

**Problem:** I've had a hard time finding effective, intelligent navigation through ms-word. I did find this article about [moving in different directions](http://word.tips.net/T000784_Moving_the_Insertion_Point_in_a_Macro.html) 
which is really the same as the arrow keys. Was hoping to get some insight into the best way to navigate the word document. For example should I do a loop of moving to the right 1 space until I find something meaningful or is there a more effective way?

**Question:** Is it possible to store a specific form location in a variable or does ms-word have no coordinate system?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: + 1 For a nicely explained question. In word you can use `.Find` or `For loops` or `GoTo` to navigate around your document. If you have form fields then you not need loops at all. I am curious as to why do you wan to store the location in a variable? You can directly work with the content controls using their name.

Comment: @SiddharthRout I figured I could probably refer to components by name, but wasn't sure of the syntax for this. However, my curiousity about storing coordinates in a variable wasn't necessarily completely relevant to this question although it could be helpful

Comment: Here is a very basic example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10823874/with-a-word-contentcontrol-datepicker-how-do-i-get-the-value/10824117#10824117

Comment: Another one : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh314613.aspx and another one :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/221300/what-are-the-benefits-of-ms-word-content-controls

Comment: @SiddharthRout maybe a foolish question, but how do i locate the name of a form field if the form field has been given a name at all? If I use the bookmark for the form field like this: `ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("myBookmark").Range.InsertBefore "Inserted Text"` sometimes text is inserted outside of the form field and the form field becomes useless

Comment: If the document is not protected then you can right click on the control and check the properties. You can also write a small vba code which will give you the names of all content controls in the active document. If you have a sample file then maybe I can post an answer with a small tutorial ;)

Comment: @SiddharthRout what I really need to find is how to find names to the formfields, you'll see this in the updated question I posted below :P

Comment: Ok gimme 15 mins. I will post an answer

Comment: Also, how to set formfield result. I assume that will be in there

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are at least three types of Form Field in recent Windows version of Word - Content Controls, "Legacy Form Fields" and ActiveX Form Fields. Assuming you are dealing with Legacy Form Fields, you should be able to index the FormFields collection using the bookmark name, then use, e.g.

```
ActiveDocument.FormFields("Text1").Result = "mytextformfieldresult"

ActiveDocument.FormFields("DropDown1").Result = "mydropdownformfieldresult"

ActiveDocument.FormFields("Check1").Checkbox.Value = True
```

Comment: simple and did what I wanted it to.

Answer (score 13):

To work with the content controls, you have to ensure that you have set the `Title` of the control. You can also set the `Tag` as well if you want. See Snapshot

[image]

And then you can use this code to update the content control or retrieve it's value

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim cc As ContentControl

    For Each cc In ActiveDocument.ContentControls
        If cc.Title = "MyTextBox1" Then
            cc.Range.Text = "Hello World!"
            Exit For
        End If
    Next cc
End Sub
```

When you run the code, this is how it looks

[image]

To get the control's text you can use `Debug.Print cc.Range.text`

Comment: I actually used this code now because I got a different letter document that used content controls instead of form fields. Thanks :p

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to create bookmarks at various places in the document that you need to go to.  In modern Word, this is on the "Insert" tab, in the "Links" group.  Then you can access the bookmarks from VBA and insert text into them with this sort of code:

```
ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("myBookmark").Range.InsertBefore "Inserted Text"
```

This [MVP site](http://word.mvps.org/FAQs/MacrosVBA/WorkWithBookmarks.htm) has more data on the technique.  Also, [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb211822%28v=office.12%29.aspx) has some data on bookmark objects.

Comment: This was really helpful. Someone else made this Document with the form fields and each form field had bookmark listed for it under text1, text2, text3...etc I'm going to try and refer to these bookmarks (or possibly the controls by name as Siddharth was saying). I'll let you know what I come up with. Thanks dsolimano