# Edit word document through excel

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

i am trying to have VBA open up a specific word document (this document is protected but has boxes where you are able to edit text). i will then need to fill out said word documents editable areas with variables in the excel document. i have no idea where to start with this code and was posting to see if this is possible and how i could do it.

Additional note. Would it be easier to have vba create a whole new word document in the code so it can just add in all the text?

Answer (score 0):

Since there isn't any code. I'm not sure what stage you're at in this but, from how I read your question you have two ways to do this. Either have your vba code in the word document that opens an Excel file to read cells or have the excel document create a word document with information already filled out. I would recommend using Word to read Excel.

[This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11988327/filling-out-a-form-ms-word-vba-most-effective-intelligent-navigation-through-w) has information about setting fill-able values in Word. There are also a lot of resources out there to find out how to get cell values and open excel documents using VBA.

All this being said. I would say you should probably look for alternatives to all of this. Such as powerapps connecting to an excel file or change your excel file to a SQLExpress database to use that in finding data. The reason I recommend this is because it's much more scalable.